# Webdriver addon is not starting with Firefox

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have a Selenium test suite configured to run with Django & teamcity but today I have noticed that when running my tests locally, Firefox launches without the Webdriver addon bar across the bottom of the window, which is visible on the Teamcity Build agent:

[image]

I'm not aware of any changes that have happened on my machine - Git reports no changes, so does anybody have any idea what might cause FF to launch without the WD addon? I'm not actually sure where this addon comes from, I've just always been happy to see it running without me worrying about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you upgrade Firefox (either manually or automatically).

Firefox attempts to validate all Addons every time it is upgraded. It might have rejected the Webdriver addon in your case.

Comment: I wondered if this might be the case. But it isn't in the addons as a disabled addon, and as I say, I can't remember if it is it's own addon or part of the IDE.

Comment: I've upgraded my Selenium Python bindings & also downloaded the latest version of `selenium-server.jar` and WebDriver is back in FF :)